# DLL Building Question

Tags: dll, build

I have my sources split up in several directories, so for each directory I get back a DLL. Is it possible to create a DLL from several other DLL's ?

**EDIT:** I'm using C++ with Windows CE Platform Builder 6.0 ( it's not managed )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool that will do this automatically for native code DLLs. You would have create a new DLL and add the existing source code to that project. However, doing this is likely to require changes to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en)

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en)   you can download this.
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx) is Sample for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create one DLL from multiple DLLs. Any such tool would be awkward since each DLL could have it's own DllMain.

You CAN create a DLL from multiple static libraries though. It shouldn't be too hard to reconfigure your setup that way.

Comment: Could you please detail a bit ?